# Changes XML file character encoding

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I want to make something like this?

User clicks on download link(download will be a xml file) programm changes XML character encoding to UTF-8 and after that downloads the file.

I know how to make a download link on servlets, but how to I changes the XML encoding in a xml file?
Hope someone can help.

Cheers!

Comment: Just curious, is there any specific reason to change encoding ?

Comment: Read the file and write it with a different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear.

- You can declarate that xml is encoded
  xml  encoding="ISO-8859-1"
- or provide response.setEncoding
- or convert encoding with String
  constructor

Comment: Something like this?
byte[] fileBytes = getBytesFromFile(file);
String newString = new String(fileBytes,"UTF-8");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(newString.getBytes());

Comment: The thing is when the file is uploaded its encoding is ISO-8859-4 and if its has these caracters in it äõö then it will not show them. So I want to change the encoding to UTF-8. I tried something like this
byte[] fileBytes = getBytesFromFile(file);
String newString = new String(fileBytes,"UTF-8");
out.write(newString.getBytes());

But it doesnt change the encoding its still 8859-4